# ResignFirstResponder in ABNewPersonViewController after editing

Tags: iphone, resignfirstresponder, abpersonviewcontroller

On a class that subclasses `ABNewPersonViewController` in edit mode, I am loading a transparent view(xib file).

When I am doing some edits, the keyboard pops up and even after I am loading the next view, the keyboard won't dismiss.

Where should I be resigning the first responder?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to call `endEditing` on the view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resign it when your view is dissapearing, for example in:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[myTextView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Whats the myTextView in this case. I am editing the `ABNewPersonViewController` here. I am editing the fields in the view controller.

Comment: Is the textView which keyboard is displayed

Comment: I am talking about editing the fields in the above image. How to dismiss the keyboard here

Answer (score 0):

Assign UITextFieldDelegate and write this method to resign your keyboard

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [TextFieldName resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Hope this may help you.Thanks!!